# Windows XP SP3 (Legal) download?

Tags: windows-xp, download, license-key

I have my CD-key sticker with me but don't have the CD anymore. Is there anywhere I can download **Windows XP SP3** installation disc from?

Answer (score 8):

If you have a sticker that is on the side of a computer, it is an OEM licence and only valid for the machine it came with. Contact your system builder who should be able to order you a new one for a minimal charge + shipping.

If you have a fully packaged product and can not find the CD, [contact Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/), who again for a minimal charge + shipping should be able to order you a new media kit. Alternatively, if you have a [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) or [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com) Subscription, you may get lucky (but not always) and download a version from there and using your serial key.

Comment: "Minimal charge" is a relative statement.  Fees can vary greatly from manufacturer to manufacturer, and some companies that issued the OEM license no longer exist.  Some manufacturers have very friendly policies about OS discs, but not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a Windows XP SP3 download for virtualization:

> #### Windows XP Mode
>
> Windows XP Mode for Windows 7 makes it easy to install and run many of your productivity programs that run on Windows XP directly from a computer that runs Windows 7.
>
> Windows XP Mode provides a 32-bit virtual Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 (SP3) environment. **This download includes a virtual hard disk (.vhd file) with Windows XP SP3 preinstalled.** Client virtualization software, such as Windows Virtual PC is required to use Windows XP Mode.
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8002

---

The "Windows XP Mode for Windows 7" download will give you a `WindowsXPMode_en-us.exe` file.

To isolate the virtual hard disk, use an archiver app such as [Keka](https://www.keka.io/). Right-click any `.exe` file and Open With to extract it.

1. Download `WindowsXPMode_en-us.exe`, extract to `WindowsXPMode_en-us`
2. In the `sources` folder, rename `xpm` to `xpm.exe` and extract it.
3. In the resulting new `xpm` folder, find the `VirtualXPVHD` file.
4. Rename `VirtualXPVHD` to `VirtualXP.VHD` by inserting a period before the file extension.

`VirtualXP.VHD` is the Virtual Hard Disk that can be loaded by a Virtual Machine.

Comment: The issue here is that it will not activate and you can not enter a licence key.

Answer (score 0):

**Obsolete answer retained for historic reasons. All links are now dead, unfortunately.**

---

In case the ISO is needed to create a virtual machine, there is legal download links for ready to use VMs for different IE and OS versions for different hypervisors at
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/.

Windows XP virtual machines were once legally available there too.
While they were hidden from combobox now, the download links are still live:

https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE8/Windows/IE8.XP.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip
https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VMware/IE8/Windows/IE8.XP.For.Windows.VMware.zip
https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/HyperV_2012/IE8/Windows/IE8.XP.For.Windows.HyperV_2012.zip

I was able to recontruct them via hint at https://github.com/magnetikonline/linuxmicrosoftievirtualmachines.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any MSDN, TechNet or similar subscription I don't think there is any possible way for you to download MS software legally.

The other thing is you may as well have an OEM version, which is usually branded and follows different key patterns than regular retail version. If your case is about an OEM version, you could contact your local retailer of your particular brand and see if they can provide you with an OEM installation CD if they have it at all. As much as I know, most brands these days already pre-install OS on the installed hard disk.

Comment: Just found an OEM version on torrent thats specifically upload for those who've lost their CDs

Comment: If it's on Torrent it's high probability that it's not legal.