# Windows XP doesnt work. I have legal license, how to reinstall without the source disk

Tags: windows, windows-xp, license, license-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP SP3 (Legal) download?](https://superuser.com/questions/88459/windows-xp-sp3-legal-download)

I bought a computer with windows XP a few years ago. XP stopped working (probably a virus) and I need to install it again. I have the sticker with microsoft license and cd key.

How can I get/download the XP install disk which will work with

Comment: @Nir Post the brand of PC please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the manufacturer and model as well as the serial number.  Then look up the manufacturer's website and generally somewhere in their support area they probably have an OS/Recovery CD that you can purchase for about 20 to 25 bucks.

Alternatively since you DO have the Key and a valid CoA, you COULD hop onto Bit Torrents and attempt to find the OEM installation ISO.  In the case of Dells this is generally pretty easy to do but if you don't get the right image, more than likely that Key from your CoA will be useless.

If you will post your model/maker and Serial Number I'd be happy to try and help you look it up from either source (the Manufacture OS disk or the Bit Torrent)

Comment: eventually I found an OEM disk from another computer, installed it and did activation via phone with Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

If it's a big brand machine you can probably get recovery disks from the manufacturer and wipe the drive and start from factory default.

Answer (score -1):

Use the SysInternals tools to stop the malware processes on your existing XP install, then update your AV.

http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/SysinternalsMalwareCleaning.pdf

Comment: too late for that

Comment: Yeah I am sorry to downvote ya but this did not seem like a helpful starting point considering where the asker started out at.

Comment: No worries about the downvote. Just where I usually start helping family members who have _always_ lost their OEM disks.