# Where can I download Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, download, iso-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP SP3 (Legal) download?](https://superuser.com/questions/88459/windows-xp-sp3-legal-download)

I need to install Windows XP as a dual boot on one of my Machines.

I have a (valid) XP product key, but I don't have the original install CD.

Where can I download XP from?

Comment: It is my understanding Microsoft is not sending out copies of Microsoft Windows XP at this time.  There is really no legal way to download it at this time except through TechNet and MSDN subscriptions.

Answer (score -3):

I just grabbed the following [from some random website](https://superuser.com/questions/88459/windows-xp-sp3-legal-download):

> If you have a sticker that is on the side of a computer, it is an OEM
>   licence and only valid for the machine it came with. Contact your
>   system builder who should be able to order you a new one for a minimal
>   charge + shipping.
>
> If you have a fully packaged product and can not find the CD, contact
>   Microsoft, who again for a minimal charge + shipping should be able to
>   order you a new media kit. Alternatively, if you have a MSDN or
>   Technet Subscription, you may get lucky (but not always) and download
>   a version from there and using your serial key.

**EDIT :** *I've just found some more recent information [here](https://superuser.com/questions/503534/where-can-i-download-windows-xp)*.

Comment: +1 The "from some random website" is a post on SuperUser itself.