# How to reinstall XP on a reformatted hard drive without a backup disk

Tags: windows-xp, reinstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows XP SP3 (Legal) download?](https://superuser.com/questions/88459/windows-xp-sp3-legal-download)

My hard drive crashed, and it was removed, reformatted and repartitioned, and reinstalled on my 7 year old Compaq Presario.  Now the pc wont boot because it doesn't have an operating system on it.  I never made the CD back up.  Is there a site where I can download XP if I have a valid product key?  I want to reinstall XP on this pc so that it works again.

Answer (score 2):

With Windows XP, legally, the answer is no - sorry I can't really be more help.

If you contact HP, they should be able to resend you a replacement - last time I needed to do this for a client, it cost £15 + £2.95 P&P (several years ago).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to locate the media somehow. If HP won't sell it to you, then you'll have to start looking on E-bay or something.